# R: remove numbers from charachter vector

Tags: r, numbers, character

I've got the next vector in R:

```
 vec <- c("hello","3","-52","b2b","1j","place")
```

Now I want to remove "3" and "-52", but I do NOT want to remove "b2b" and "1j".

And what can I add to the code to remove also numbers like "40" in the following vector:

```
vec2 <- c("hello","3","-52","b2b","1j","place 40")
```

Comment: `vec[is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(vec)))]`

Comment: `vec[grep("^[-]*[[:digit:]]+$", vec, invert=TRUE)]`

Comment: ``vec[grep("[a-z]+", vec)]``

Comment: It works! Thanks! Is there even a possibility to replace these numbers by " "?

Comment: `gsub("^[0-9-]+$", " ", vec)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your vector is:

```
 vec1 <- c("hello", "3", "-52", "b25b", "+22", "1j5", "place", "32.50")
 gsub("^[-+]?[0-9.]+$", " ", vec1)
 #[1] "hello" " "     " "     "b25b"  " "     "1j5"   "place" " "
```

Also works for `vec`

```
 gsub("^[-+]?[0-9.]+$", " ", vec)
 #[1] "hello" " "     " "     "b2b"   "1j"    "place"
```